# Eslint React Hooks Error: eslint-plugin-react-hooks exhaustive deps warning for a function dependency in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Actions from '../actions';

export const UserComponent = ({ foo, baz, bar, user, fetchUser }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('##### I WAS CALLED I WAS CALLED');
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        <p>{user.name}</p>
        <p>{foo} {baz} {bar}</p>
      </div>
  );
};

UserComponent.propTypes = {
  fetchUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

const mapActionsToProps = {
  fetchUser: Actions.fetchUser,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ data }) => ({
  user: data.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(UserComponent);
```

I get an error 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency`

But If I put `fetchUser` in the dependency array

```js
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('##### I WAS CALLED I WAS CALLED');
        fetchUser();
      }, [fetchUser]);
```

It causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the dependency array entirely, with `useEffect(() => {fetchUser()});`? In other words, don't pass a second argument to `useEffect`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. I have multiple props being passed to the component & I don't want to run useEffect every time those props change. I just want to fetch the users for the first time & not every time all the API's change.

Comment: What about using `user` as the second argument to `useEffect`, as you only want to update when `user` is changed. As in `useEffect(() => {fetchUser()}, [user]);`

Comment: Yes true, but since I am using `fetchUser` in `useEffect` eslint error shows that I should add `fetchUser` in the dependency array as well.

Comment: Well, there's always `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: Does `fetchUser()` update the `user` prop?

Comment: Solved it, I was using redux the wrong way in hooks. https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: It would be helpful to others who find this to post your solution as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using redux the wrong way in hook based components. This guide helped me a lot to use `redux` in functional components using hooks. https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the function fetchUser changes in each render. 
You can solve the problem using "useCallback".

Example:

```
const initFetchMethod = useCallback(() => {
   return dispatch(fetchUserAction())
}, [dispatch])


useEffect(() => {
   initFetchMethod();
}, [initFetchMethod]);
```

References:

- [React Hooks Api Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)
- [React-Redux Hooks Api Reference](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks)

Answer (score -1):

The error says, you need to put all resources(vars/functions) used by the effect callback inside the dependencies array.

So, you need to put fetchUsers in the dependencies array.
But, it will cause infinite loop. Because, fetchUsers instance is recreated everytime.

You need to maintain a loading state for the api response.
And, put a check in the callback like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!user && !loading ) {
        fetchUser();
    }
}, [fetchUser, user]);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Disable the es-lint warning if `fetchUser` action does not change in app lifecycle**

Since fetchUser is an redux action and it is not going to change in your app lifecycle, i would say you can safely disable the rule for your case.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('##### I WAS CALLED I WAS CALLED');
    fetchUser();
    //eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
  }, []);
```